# formatting character arrays

Tags: string, matlab, datetime, matrix, cell-array

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Counting values by day/hour with timeseries in MATLAB](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11671588/counting-values-by-day-hour-with-timeseries-in-matlab)

This is an elementary question, but I cannot find it:

I have a 3000x25 character array:

`2000-01-01T00:01:01+00:00`
`2000-01-01T00:01:02+00:00`
`2000-01-01T00:01:03+00:00`
`2000-01-01T00:01:04+00:00`

These are obviously times. I want to reformat the array to be a 3000x1 array. How can I redefine each row to be one entry in an array?

(Again, this is simple, I'm sorry)

Answer (score 3):

Other than converting to serial date numbers as other have shown, I think you simply wanted to convert to cell array of strings:

```
A = cellstr(c)
```

where `c` is the 3000x25 matrix of characters.

Comment: Thanks, this is what I was looking for. I'm still not sure how serial dates would achieve what I'm trying to do. (See my comment below).

Answer (score 1):

You need to specify a format for the array and feed it to `datenum`, like this:

```
>> d = datenum(c,'YYYY-MM-DDTHH:mm:ss')
d =
  1.0e+005 *
    7.3487
    7.3487
    7.3487
    7.3487
```

The times are now stored as datenums, i.e. as floating point numbers representing the number of days elapsed since the start of the Matlab epoch. If you want to convert these to numbers representing the fraction of the day elapsed, you can do

```
>> t = d - fix(d);
```

and if you want the number of seconds since midnight, you can do

```
>> t = 86400 * (d - fix(d));
t =
   61.0000
   62.0000
   63.0000
   64.0000
```

Comment: Thanks for the response, but I don't understand something about this approach: If I'm trying to create an array of events per day, wouldn't I have to create a new function for each day? I would like something like: "Day1: 85"<br/> "Day2: 43"

Comment: @ehertele: I'm not sure I understand what the goal is. DATENUM converts the string dates into numbers representing timestamps, expressed in units of fraction of days from some reference point. You can always go back to string representation of dates using the equivalent DATESTR function

Comment: (Excuse me if I'm not following something)
I have an array of timestamps which are events. If I convert these to serial numbers, how would you then bin the events by date so that you know how many events happen per day (or per hour)? So far, I see how you would calculate events between two serial numbers, but this is not reasonable for such a large array. 
This is what I mean by "date1: 38" / "date2:23" / etc.

Comment: @Amro
Ah, I see you may not have seen the question previous to this...hopefully I've explained what my goal is above.

Comment: @ehertele: I've posted an [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/11680040/97160) to your other question