# MATLAB: Find all values on one date, then filter down to an hour and find average

Tags: matlab, datetime

I have a year's worth of data, the data is recorded one minute intervals each day of the year.

The date and time was imported from excel (in form 243.981944, then by adding 42004 (so will be for 2015) and formatting to date it becomes 31.8.15 23:34:00).

Importing to MATLAB it becomes
'31/08/2015 23:34:00'

I require the data for each day of the year to be at hourly intervals, so I need to sum the data recorded in each hour and divide that by the number of data recorded for that hour, giving me the hourly average.

For some reason the data in August actually increments in 2 minute intervals, data for every other month increments in one minute intervals.
ie

`...
31/07/2015 23:57:00
31/07/2015 23:58:00
31/07/2015 23:59:00
31/08/2015 00:00:00
31/08/2015 00:02:00
31/08/2015 00:04:00
...`

I'm not sure how I can find all the values for a specific date and hour in order to work out the averages. I was thinking of using a for loop to find the values on each day, but when I got down to writing code realised this wouldn't work the way I was thinking.
I presume there must be some kind of functions available that would allow for data to be filtered by the date and time?

edit:

So I tried the following but I get these errors.
`dates` is a 520000x1 cell array containing the dates form = formatIn.

```
 formatIn = 'DD/MM/YYYY HH:MM:SS';
 [~,M,D,H] = datevec(dates, formatIn);

 Error using cnv2icudf (line 131) Unrecognized minute format.
 Format string: DD/MM/YYYY HH:MM:SS.

 Error in datevec (line 112) icu_dtformat = cnv2icudf(varargin{isdateformat});`
```

Comment: Check [`datenum`](http://mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/datenum.html). Just use a logical for everything between two subsequent datenums, which you'll want one hour apart.

Comment: How can I use datenum though? My understanding of datenum is essentially it converts a say 01 01 2015 00:00:01 to a serial date number. If I was going to use a logical for anything between tow datenums, I'd need to know the datenum values for each hour of the year surely? Which I do not know.

Comment: `datenum` converts to a serial date which is days after 1 January 1970 iirc. All decimal numbers are your decimal "date" i.e. your hours, minutes, seconds. Those you can use to check between two subsequent hours, like `SerialDayNo = datenum(15/07/2015); SerialDayNo+1/24<x<SerialDayNo+2/24` checks for occurances between 01:00 and 02:00 on 17 July 2015.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming your data is in a matrix or cell-array of strings called `A`, and your other data is in a vector `X`. Let's say all the data is in the same year (so we can ignore years)

```
[~,M,D,H] = datevec(A, 'dd/mm/yyyy HH:MM:SS');

mean_A = accumarray([M, D, H+1], X, [], @mean);
```

Then data from February will be in

```
mean_A(2,:,:)
```

To look at the data, you may find the `squeeze()` function useful, e.g.

```
squeeze(mean_A(2,1:10,13:24))
```

shows the average for the hours after midday (by column) for the first ten days (by row) of February.

See also:

[Counting values by day/hour with timeseries in MATLAB](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11671588/counting-values-by-day-hour-with-timeseries-in-matlab?rq=1)

Comment: If you don't need the year because the data is all from one year, then replace `[Y,M,D,H]` with `[~,M,D,H]` and then remove the `Y+1-min(Y)`, and the data from February would be in `M(2,:,:)`

Comment: `[~,M,D,H] = datevec(dates, 'DD/MM/YYYY HH:MM:SS');
Error using cnv2icudf (line 131)
Unrecognized minute format.  Format string: DD/MM/YYYY HH:MM:SS.

Error in datevec (line 112)
        icu_dtformat = cnv2icudf(varargin{isdateformat});
 `

Comment: I tested it in Octave, in matlab I think the correct string is `'dd/mm/yyyy HH:MM:SS'`

Comment: I've tried it with formatIn = `'dd/mm/yyyy HH:MM:SS',

Comment: and also `dd/mm/yyyy hh:mm:ss'` and `'dd/mm/yyyy hh:mnmn:ss'` along with similar ones by in the complementary lower/uppercase

Comment: However I still get errors coming from this line `[~,M,D,H] = datevec(DateString, formatIn);` either
    Error using dtstr2dtvecmx
    Failed on converting date string to date number.
    Error in datevec (line 117)
            y = dtstr2dtvecmx(t,icu_dtformat);

or

     Error using cnv2icudf (line 131)
     Unrecognized minute format.  Format string: DD/MM/YYYY HH:MM:SS.
     Error in datevec (line 112)
             icu_dtformat = cnv2icudf(varargin{isdateformat});

Comment: Does the command `datevec('01/02/2003 02:03:04', 'dd/mm/yyyy HH:MM:SS')` work?

Comment: The line alone works yes, not with the accumarry line though

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/126444/discussion-between-stephen-wade-and-maitiu).